# Bokeh: Barchart with relative Barmode

Tags: python, bar-chart, bokeh

I am trying to implement a barchart with “relative Barmode” in Bokeh. In particular, I would like to achieve a barchart with two groups (a, b). If a is positive it should be on top of b, however, if a is negative it should be under the x-axis and below b. A chart which visualizes my wish using plotly is here:
https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-relative-barmode

Does anyone of you know how I can implement such visualization using bokeh barchart?

Thanks
Andy